# Writing to a file from multiple threads in the correct order

Tags: python, multithreading, file

I'm trying to read in a file, translate it using a remote api endpoint, then write it to a file.

It was really slow due to each request taking 2-3 seconds, so I've opted to using threads to speed up the translation by hitting the endpoint multiple times in parallel (As recommended in their api docs)

However I'm having trouble coming up with a way to write the translated lines in the correct order. Race Conditions I suppose. I'm thinking the issue is that I'm writing to a single file from multiple threads. So I would need a queue or something, but I have no idea how to approach it.

Main()

```
#Open File
for filename in os.listdir("files"):
    with open('translate/' + filename, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as outFile:
        with open ('files/' + filename, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            count = 0

            #Replace Each Line
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
                future_to_url = (executor.submit(findMatch, line, count) for line in f)
                for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
                    print(future)
```

FindMatch()

```
def findMatch(line, count):
    count = count + 1   #Keep track of lines for debugging
    #Check if match in line
    if(re.search(pattern1, line) != None):

        #Translate each match in line. Depends on choice
        for match in re.findall(pattern1, line):

            #Filter out matches with no Japanese
            if(re.search(pattern2, match) != None and '$' not in match):
                if(choice == '1'):
                    match = match.rstrip()
                    print('Translating: ' + str(count) + ': ' + match)
                    translatedMatch = translate(match)
                    line = re.sub(match, translatedMatch, line, 1)

                elif(choice == '2'):
                    match = match.rstrip()
                    print('Translating Line: ' + str(count))
                    line = translate(line)
                    break       #Don't want dupes

                else:
                    print('Bad Coder. Check your if statements')

        outFile.write(line)

    #Skip Line
    else:
        print('Skipping: ' + str(count))
        outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Use ProcessPoolExecutor instead. The thread executor is limited by the GIL.

Comment: @Aaron ProcessPoolExecutor gives me a weird result for some reason. It seems to create a new process for the entire program?

Comment: The objects in one process may not be pickled to another process. For example, the file object or nested functions.

Comment: Is the endpoint a remote server? then the blocking is IO intensive instead of CPU and threads may work. To avoid the ordering issue, parallelize files or label each line by its id and sort the result set.

Comment: Yes the endpoint is remote, each request takes around 2-3 seconds to process.

Comment: I updated the answer to sort the line by their indices. Parallelize lines are okay but the results must be sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write lines in correct order,

1. Use `for future in future_to_url` to iterate the futures in the submission order.
2. Use list comprehension `[execuotr.submit(...) for line in f]` instead of generator expression `(execuotr.submit(...) for line in f)`. All lines are submitted to the executor at once. Otherwise, tasks are submitted on-demand one-by-one while the loop is iterated, which is not parallelized.
3. `findMatch()` return the result rather than write to the output directly.

When the call `future.result()` is made, it returns immediately the result if available, or block and wait the result.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import os


def main():
    # Open File
    for filename in os.listdir("files"):
        with open('translate/' + filename, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as outFile:
            with open('files/' + filename, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
                count = 0

                # Replace Each Line
                with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:

                    # The following submit all lines
                    future_to_url = [executor.submit(findMatch, line, count) for line in f]

                    # as_completed return arbitrary future when it is done
                    # Use simple for-loop ensure the future are iterated sequentially
                    for future in future_to_url:
                        print(future.result())
                        # Uncomment to actually write to the output
                        # outFile.write(future.result())


def findMatch(line, count):
    count = count + 1  # Keep track of lines for debugging
    # Check if match in line
    if (re.search(pattern1, line) != None):

        # Translate each match in line. Depends on choice
        for match in re.findall(pattern1, line):

            # Filter out matches with no Japanese
            if (re.search(pattern2, match) != None and '$' not in match):
                if (choice == '1'):
                    match = match.rstrip()
                    print('Translating: ' + str(count) + ': ' + match)
                    translatedMatch = translate(match)
                    line = re.sub(match, translatedMatch, line, 1)

                elif (choice == '2'):
                    match = match.rstrip()
                    print('Translating Line: ' + str(count))
                    line = translate(line)
                    break  # Don't want dupes

                else:
                    print('Bad Coder. Check your if statements')

        return line
    # Skip Line
    else:
        print('Skipping: ' + str(count))

        return line
```

Comment: This is giving me the issue `A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.` as well as running multiple instances of the user input. https://ibb.co/PFcFsVT

Comment: @DazedFury updated to return result from function and write lines in correct order.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Can you explain to me the main changes you made? Was it just `for future in fs:`?

Comment: @DazedFury and the list comprehension, and function return.

Comment: what do the brackets do in `fs = [executor.submit(findMatch, line) for line in f]`? I noticed that using parenthesis instead makes it much slower.

Comment: @DazedFury parenthesis `(... for ... in ...)` mean generator. it generate the items on-demand. which mean the file is not read at all until the generator is iterated. while `[... for ... in ...]` construct a list completely: the whole file is read and submit to the executor.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution would be for `findMatch` to take a string as an argument and return its translation as a string.  Your main program would then be responsible for sorting all the translations and printing them out in order.

Attempting to synchronize multiple threads all writing to a single file is a big mess.

Comment: That makes sense, when I get the translated string back from future.result() how do I ensure it's written in the correct order?

Comment: You just look at multiprocessing.Pool, and then look at `pool.imap()`.  This returns an iterator that gives you each of your results in order, and handles all the internals for you.